# How do I pass around data between pages in a GAE app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a fairly basic GAE app that takes some input, fetches some data from a webpage, parses, then presents it to the user.  Right now, the fairly spare input HTML form POSTs the arguments to the output 'file' which is wholly generated by the handler for that URL.

I'd like to do a couple things with the data (e.g. graph it at a landing page perhaps, then write it to an output file), but I don't know how I should pass the parsed data between the different handlers.  I could maybe encode it then successively POST it to other handlers, but my gut says that I shouldn't need to HTTP the data back and forth within my app—it seems terribly inefficient (my gut is also hungry...).

In fairly broad swaths (or maybe a link to an example), how should my handlers handle this?

#### Later thoughts (edit)

My very rough idea now is to have the form submitted to a page that 1) enters the subsequent query into a database (`datastore`?) keyed to some hash, then uses that to 2) grab and parse all the data.  The parsed data would be stored in memory (`memcache`?) for near-immediate use to graph it and/or process it into a variety of tabular formats for download.  The script that does said parsing redirects to a unique URL based on the hash which can be referred to in order to get the data.

The thought would be that you could save the URL, then if you visit it later when the data has been lost, it can re-query the source to get it back/update it.

Reasonable?  Should I be looking at other things?

Comment: GAE is no different to any other web based application.  You choices are cookies, sessions, the database (datastore in gae), memcache (though unreliable).

Comment: This is the first time I've coded any web apps, so I have a really poor understanding of those options.  Guess it's a place to start searching in docs.

Comment: Yep, you should probably state that at the outset.  Also what language (python/java/go) you are planning to work with on appengine. If you are using python then this might be one possible place to start https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/py101_1/

Comment: Python.  That link is a bit generic and doesn't quite solve my problem.  I can handle form requests and many of the basics just fine, I'm asking about how to implement some sort of persistence across multiple pages.

Comment: You did say "first time" so I stopped assuming your knowledge level ;-)

Comment: The correct strategy for accessing data between a series of requests will depend on 1. how much data, 2. how long do you need it.

Comment: I updated my question with my hopefully-not-so-pie-eye'd notion.  In any event, it's not a massive amount of data, like a 15x15 float array.